# How to store multiple variables locally in Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-sqlite, sharedpreferences

I want to make an app with **n** different quizzes. When restarting the app I want the users last score to be shown for the **n** quizzes. How do I do that?

I have seen examples when one store a single variable. But I do not know how to make it work when one wants to store multiple values/strings locally.

Comment: You can save a list of values using shared preferences by encoding your list

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to store an array if you JsonEncode it first.

```
List dailygoals = ['apple', 'banana'];
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
dailygoals.add('orange');
prefs.setString('dailygoals', jsonEncode(dailygoals));
```